# Typescript: Omit<T,K> does not work for enums

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a enum and interface like this

```
enum MyEnum {
    ALL, OTHER
}

interface Props {
    sources: Omit<MyEnum, MyEnum.ALL>
}

const test: Props = { sources: MyEnum.ALL } // should complain
```

Why does it not omit `MyEnum.All`? I am using typescript 3.6.4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Omit` is to omit keys from an interface. But enums are something different.

Imo the best comparison of an enum would be a union of instances of that enum type. Like `type MyEnum = MyEnum.All | MyEnum.OTHER`.

So you do not want to OMIT keys, but exclude types from an union type:

```
enum MyEnum {
    ALL, OTHER, SOME, MORE
}

interface Props {
    sources: Exclude<MyEnum, MyEnum.ALL | MyEnum.SOME>
}

const test: Props = { sources: MyEnum.ALL } // does complain now
```

Comment: Perfect. I was actually using `Exclude` beforehand, but the ts-compiler did not highlight the error.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for `Exclude` utility type:

```
 sources: Exclude<MyEnum, MyEnum.ALL>
```